# Create a script to run update on startup

Tags: boot, apt, scripts

I'm trying to create a script that upon booting up Ubuntu it opens up a terminal which runs `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`. I managed to make said script, how I can open a terminal upon boot/reboot and make it run the script? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it "at startup", you're already running as `UID 0`, so use of `sudo` is incorrect and shoule be removed.

Also, "at startup" is the wrong environment to run `apt` (documented as `It is intended as an end user interface and enables some options better suited for interactive usage by default`. Use `apt-get` instead. Thus:

```
apt-get -q=2 -y update && apt-get -q=2 -y upgrade
```

is closer to what you want. Read `man apt-get` or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt-get.8.html

Comment: What does `-q=2` or `--q=2` respectively and `-y` do?

Comment: @dessert you can find that info using `man apt-get` as was suggested in the answer -- it says that -q means "quiet" and -y means "automatic yes to prompts". See `man apt-get` for more details.

Comment: @Elias There is no option `--q` and what the proposed command does should definitely be part of the answer.

Comment: I see... do I write these commands as a script then?